# Is it necessary to explicitly call iter() on a custom iterator class in python?

Tags: python, iterator

Image we have this custom iterator class:

```
class Counter: 
             def __init__(self, low,high):
                    self.current=low-1 
                    self.high=high
              def __iter__(self):
                    return self
              def __next__(self):
                     self.current+=1
                     if self.current  < self.high:
                                return self.current
                      raise StopIterationError
```

Is it necessary to call `iter()` on the object and then call `next()` on it? (I don't want to use a for loop)

```
Obj=Counter(1,10)
i=iter(Obj)
print(next(i))
```

Or:

```
Obj=Counter(1,10)
print(next(Obj))
```

Both seem to work.

Comment: Nope it' isn't ;)

Comment: I mean, in what case we should call iter() explicitly? When we have some statements inside __ iter __?

Comment: *in what case* → when you want to implement a loop manually, rather than using `for`.

Comment: @iBug so in my third snippet i'm not using a for loop and have not used iter() either, but it still works

Comment: It's an iterator already. `iter()` is for obtaining an iterator from another "container" class (list, tuple, etc.). Implementing `__iter__` for an iterator class is for compatibility reasons.

Comment: `iter()` accepts a second `sentinal` argument, when `__next__` returns this value iteration is stopped

Comment: @iBug how is it an iterator class without using __ iter __? Is it because of __ next __?

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration

Answer (score 1):

Creating a iterator (calling `iter(...)`) from an iterable that already is an iterator is a no-op. This explains why both of your snippets work the same way.

Now, what makes an iterator?
It is the implementation of `__next__` methods as you did. `__iter__` magic function is used when you call `iter` on it. Typically, both of the methods are implemented together.

So, an instance of your class is already an iterator and there is no need to create one.

It is worth noting too, that typically iterators are just used in `for` loops where `next` or `__next__` is called implicitly. So your test of iterator - `next(i)` is like one cycle of a `for` loop on the iterator.

Comment: Deleting __ iter __ from the class still makes it work. So i assume only __ next __ is what makes that class an iterator not __ iter __

Comment: So why should i implement __ iter __ in my custom iterator class?

Comment: Because if your class is iterable (but is not inheriting this feature from the base class) it is customary to expect that you can turn it into iterator with `iter`. And many libraries might expect such a contract is held.